# What is the best way to test a video chat application locally?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, video-streaming, videochat, opentok

If I am running a local server that is hosting a video chat application what is the best way to test the application with another user? Lets say I have two computers, is there a way I can allow computer B to connect to the local server that is running on computer A? The goal is to simply test whether the video chat application works properly in two completely different browsers running on separate computers. If there is a way I can trick the app into thinking the computer that is running the local server is another host, please let me know.
But Remember that the app needs access to the computers webcam. Thanks!

Addition Info: Nodejs application that uses the Tokbox, express, and socket.io APIs

Comment: Please share your code. I need video chat in my web application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure your web server is listening on a routable IP like "0.0.0.0", which you specify when you call `http.createServer(port, ip, handler)`. Then point the browsers at the server's IP address such as `http://192.168.1.1:3000` (fill in your specific IP and port). You can use the command `ifconfig -a` on linux or osx to get your server's local IP address, and `ipconfig` on windows.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I had to turnoff the windows firewall to allow the computers to talk, but your solution worked like a charm. Regards!